# Problems getting started--Http 403

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm trying to access the SmartSheets REST API as described in the "Getting Started" documentation here: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#getting-started and elsewhere. I generated an access token in the UI and, using Postman, tried a couple of simple GET requests cribbed from the documentation:

https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/users/me

https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets

I set the Authorization and Content-Type headers as indicated. In both cases, I get Http 403-Forbidden errors with the message "You are not authorized to perform this action."

So how do I get authorized to perform these (or any other) actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo. I was including "Bearer" in the authorization header, but I had 2 spaces between "Bearer"and the token. You can only have one.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to verify that your access token value is correct. Also, when you set your Authorization header, are you including "Bearer " before your access token?

In Postman, it should look something like this:
[image]